# How to refer to 'depression' in Chinese?

Tags: translation

Depression is a word used to describe a 人 who feels a sadness that is buried deeply in heart and mind.

What word is used to refer to this kind of depression?

If you can think of any idioms or sayings that relates to the word 'depression' in Chinese, I would appreciate your sharing of it in the comments too.

Answer (score 4):

The common term would be 抑郁。

There is a type of mental disorder in that name, called [major depressive disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_depressive_disorder).

However, if you are not referring to the disease, you would say

> 我觉得有些沮丧
>
> 我觉得有点压抑

Comment: Is 压抑 considered "depression"? Maybe sometimes it is close, but in more broader sense it would be "opressed", no?

Comment: see e.g. https://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=%E5%8E%8B%E6%8A%91

Comment: @Blaszard I would say *oppress* is better translated to 压迫。

Comment: 压抑 is actually better translated as repressed, as in: repressed emotions, etc.

Comment: @user3306356 You are right, thanks.